Why are the bottom lines of pixels on my screen displaying inconsistent corruption?
For several weeks now, the bottom lines on my display have shown visible corruption. It manifests as random colours on coloured elements, black lines through some elements, and distortion of some elements.
I have tried removing and reinstalling GPU drivers, reseating my GPU, cleaning dust from it, and trying a different cable. My GPU temperatures are normal.
GPU is an RTX 2080. Monitor is an Acer XF273S.
An image of the bottom of the display, showing visible corruption on the cursor and taskbar.



Try a different display. If that works, the original display is the issue. 2. Try a different frame rate and/or resolution. The current settings might be just at the limit of the internal hardware or the display.


Changing the refresh rate does lessen the problem, but hasn't fixed it. Given my GPU is an RTX 2080, while a little old, it still generally runs fine, so this does seem like it might actually be a display issue. I'll check on another display.
